# integrals inequalities

Tags: integration

$$
\left( {\int\limits_0^1 {f^2(x)\ \text{d}x} }\right)^{\frac{1}
{2}} \  \geqslant \quad \int\limits_0^1 {\left| {f(x)} \right|\ \text{d}x} 
$$

I can't prove it )=

Comment: Do you know Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx = \int_0^1 |1||f(x)| \, dx \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 1 \, dx} \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 \, dx} = \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 \, dx}$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Jonas' post generalizes to the result that if p<q and there are no sets of infinite measure in S, then $L^q<L^p$, for functions in a total ambient set ( in the measure triple) S.

Answer (score 5):

Define
$$
\mu = \int_0^1 {|f(x)|\,dx} 
$$
and
$$
\sigma^2 = \int_0^1 {(|f(x)| - \mu )^2 \,dx} .
$$
Then
$$
\sigma^2 = \int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,dx}  - 2\mu \int_0^1 {|f(x)|\,dx}  + \mu ^2  = \int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,dx}  - \mu ^2 .
$$
Since $\sigma^2 \geq 0$, 
$$
\int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,dx}  \geq \mu ^2.
$$
Taking square roots of both sides yields the desired result:
$$
\bigg(\int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,dx} \bigg)^{1/2}  \ge \int_0^1 {|f(x)|\,dx}. 
$$

EDIT: The idea used here is that for a random variable $Y$ with finite second moment,
$$
{\rm Var}(Y) := {\rm E}[Y - {\rm E}(Y)]^2  \geq 0.
$$
So,
$$
{\rm Var}(Y) = {\rm E}(Y^2) - 2{\rm E}(Y){\rm E}(Y)+  {\rm E}^2 (Y) =  {\rm E}(Y^2) - {\rm E}^2 (Y),
$$
and hence
$$
{\rm E}(Y^2) \geq {\rm E}^2 (Y).
$$
To relate this to the question at hand, let $X$ be a uniform$[0,1]$ random variable, and let $Y=|f(X)|$ (for $f$ a square-integrable function on $[0,1]$).
Then
$$
{\rm E}(Y^2) = {\rm E}[f^2 (X)] = \int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,dx} 
$$
and
$$
{\rm E}^2 (Y) = {\rm E}^2 (|f(X)|) = \bigg(\int_0^1 {|f(x)|\,dx} \bigg)^2 .
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^1 {f^2 (x)\,dx}  \geq \bigg(\int_0^1 {|f(x)|\,dx} \bigg)^2 ,
$$
which gives the desired result after taking square roots.

Comment: @gary: "Jonas' post generalizes to the result ...", but Shai Covo's answer is more fundamental.

Comment: @puresky: Can you explain why it is more fundamental? I surely like it, but for me this is more a probabilistic argument and mine more analytic.

Comment: @Jonas Teuwen:your and Shai Covo's proofs can be induced frome finite situations, i.e. $\sum=>\int$, where Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(\sum {a_i b_i})^2\leqslant (\sum {a_i^2}) (\sum {b_i^2})$ is more difficult to prove than the inequality $((\sum {a_i})/n)^2\leqslant (\sum {a_i^2})/n\Leftrightarrow ((a+b)/2)^2\leqslant (a^2+b^2)/2$. While my former comment is merely to understand the proof:)